# How to filter out "jquery.js" file in the ajax return data

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter

I use a php framework (Yii) for my code which includes jquery.js in each html form automatically for its validating functions. And i can't do anything about it.

**Here is the problem:**

I get a piece of html, including the form and the jquery.js file, by ajax to show in a placeholder.
I already have a jquery.js in the page. So the second one comes in, and all other jquery plugins stop working and I should initiate them again!
I need to filter out the second jquery.js from my ajax return data.
How should i do it?

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: $params.url,
  data: $data,
  dataType: $dataType,
  success: function(data){
    // data includes jquery.js code
    callback(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a callback function with something like the following:

```
callback(data.replace(/<script.+script>/, ""));
```

Comment: `data = data.replace(/<script (.*?)src="(.*?)\/(jquery.js|jquery.min.js)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/script>/,'');`